# Como ordenar um array de objetos por sua chave com base em uma ordem definida/personalizada?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu estou o dia todo batendo a cabeça procurando uma solução, se trata de uma parte do trabalho da faculdade.

Eu tenho o seguinte obj:

```
let users = [{Lucia: 23},{Gabriela: 18},{Jose: 30},{Maria: 17},{Amanda: 26}];
```

E preciso ordenar pela `chave do objeto` conforme a `ordem definida abaixo` para adicionar no array `lista_ordenada = []` seus elementos compostos de `(chave+valor)`

```
// ORDEM DE CHAVE DEFINIDA: "Jose", 'Amanda', 'Gabriela', 'Lucia', 'Maria'
```

- Ao final o array `lista_ordenada = []` é impresso no console com a saída ordenada.

`// ["Jose 30", 'Amanda 26', 'Gabriela 18', 'Lucia 23', 'Maria 17']`

---

Meu código incompleto:

```js
let users = [{Lucia: 23},{Gabriela: 18},{Jose: 30},{Maria: 17},{Amanda: 26}];
let lista_ordenada = []

let users_list = Object.keys(users).length

for(let i=0; i<users_list; i++){
   let key = Object.keys(users[i]);
   let value = Object.values(users[i]);

   lista_ordenada.push(key+' '+value);
}

console.log(lista_ordenada) // Correta: ["Jose 30", 'Amanda 26', 'Gabriela 18', 'Lucia 23', 'Maria 17']
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom, fiz uma mudança na definição de cada objeto do seu array. pelo que entendi,  os numeros sao idades de cada pessoa, entao, o correto seria o objeto ter as propriedades name e age;

utilizei for para percorrer cada item;
segue o código testado e funcionando:

let users = [

```
{   name: "Lucia",
    age: 23
},

{   name: "Gabriela",
    age: 18
},
{   name: "Jose",
    age: 30
},

{   name: "Maria",
    age: 17
},

{   name: "Amanda",
    age: 26
}
```

];

let objectReceiver;

for(i = 0; i <users.length; i++){

```
for(j = i; j < users.length; j++){

    if(users[i].age < users[j].age){

        objectReceiver = users[i];
        users[i] = users[j];
        users[j] = objectReceiver;

    }
}
```

}

for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

```
console.log(users[i].name + ' ' + users[i].age + "\n");
```

}

> console.log(users);

você pode retirar o comentário do console.log(users); e verificar como ficou a array tambem

Comment: Agradeço imensamente sua ajuda, mas infelizmente o exercício proposto não é uma ordenação pelo valor e sim por chave com base em uma sequencia definida/personalizada. Eu infelizmente não consigo encontrar uma solução, e meus amigos de turma também estão na mesma. Acho que vou tentar um monte de condicional e justificar por incapacidade, pelo menos o objetivo será atingido.

E você tá corretíssimo sobre o Array de objetos, foi apenas um exemplo com estrutura similar, o original se trata de uma lista de ATRIBUTOS de um usuário onde seu valor é definido em 1 (sim) ou 0 (não).